# V2.0 of swagger Petstore json file

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Where can I get the 2.0 version of the Petstore swagger json?  The only URL I've been able to find is at http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs and that still has the 1.2 schema.

Answer (score 2):

You have the petstore example here, in both Json and Yaml:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/tree/master/examples/v2.0

Answer (score 2):

The V2 of the petstore and the UI is currently publicly hosted at http://petstore.swagger.io  and http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json.

We're going to change it soon so that the main link uses the V2 UI and spec.

Comment: The urls do not respond :(

Comment: Updated the links.